# Combine odd and even indexed rows in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame `df` like this,

```
   Name     Net        Quantity  
0  Auto     1010       10
1  NaN      NaN        12
2  Rtal     4145       18
3  NaN      NaN        14
4  Indl     6223       16
5  NaN      7222       18
```

My output data frame should be like this,

```
       Name     Net         Quantity  
    0  Auto     1010        10,12
    1  Rtal     4145        18,14
    2  Indl     6223,7222   16,18
```

As you can see from above data frame, I want to combine values with even number (index) of rows if there is any values present in odd number (index) so that I can get my output.

I tried the following to extract odd number values,

```
df.iloc[1::2, :]
```

this gives me the following,

```
    Name    Net   Quantity
1   NaN     NaN       12
3   NaN     NaN       14
5   NaN     7222.0    18
```

after this, I don't now how to add these values to even number indexes to my `df`. In addition to this, I am not sure if my approach is correct. I would appreciate if anyone could advise/help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're okay with floats in 'Net', you can use `groupby` and `agg`:

```
df.groupby(df.index // 2).agg(lambda x: x.dropna().astype(str).str.cat(sep=','))

   Name            Net Quantity
0  Auto         1010.0    10,12
1  Rtal         4145.0    18,14
2  Indl  6223.0,7222.0    16,18
```

---

To handle floats, the solution becomes a little more complicated; you can use `ffill` and attempt to downcast if possible.

```
df.groupby(df.index // 2).agg(
    lambda x: ','.join(x.ffill(downcast='infer').astype(str).unique()))

   Name        Net Quantity
0  Auto       1010    10,12
1  Rtal       4145    18,14
2  Indl  6223,7222    16,18
```

Answer (score 2):

To fetch even rows: df[df.index.map(lambda x: x%2==0)]

To fetch odd rows:  df[df.index.map(lambda x: x%2==1)]

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to `ffill`, then `groupby` with custom functions. Note the solution is *not* dependent explicitly on the dataframe index, and therefore will also work for the more general case where you have arbitrary `NaN` values which can be inferred from a previous row.

```
# forward fill to remove null values
df = df.ffill(downcast='infer')

# convert to str so you can use str.join later
grp_cols = ['Net', 'Quantity']
df[grp_cols] = df[grp_cols].astype(str)

# apply groupby with custom functions
res = df.groupby('Name').agg({'Net': lambda x: ','.join(np.unique(x)),
                              'Quantity': lambda x: ','.join(x)}).reset_index()

print(res)

#    Name        Net Quantity
# 0  Auto       1010    10,12
# 1  Indl  6223,7222    16,18
# 2  Rtal       4145    18,14
```